# Java Runtime : process launched by window does not open

Tags: java, glassfish, runtime.exec

I'm using glassfish server to run a java web application (on windows 7 64bits, jdk 1.7.0.67). I'm trying to launch putty from a class. The process is launched (I can see it in the task manager of windows) but no putty window is opening... I tried different code like :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL " + "C:\\putty.exe");
```

or

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\putty.exe");
```

or

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd /c start C:\\putty.exe");
```

The security manager in glassfish is disabled. The putty.exe is marked to be executed as administrator. The approach is the same with others applications : cmd.exe, or pspade.exe. If I execute code in a cmd.exe launched by the application, code is well executed. 
I've no more idea, your help will be nice!

Comment: for me your code is working. put your `putty.exe` in any other drive and check.

Comment: I put it on D:, the same...

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.  Further, break the argument `String`  into an arguments `String[]` for more reliable parsing of paths (amongst other things)..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Does not work in this case but might help in other cases.

Try adding:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new inputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));){            
  while (reader.readLine() != null){
        // consume the InputStream of the shell command
  } catch (IOException e) {
     //might throw an Exception if reader is not closed properly
  }
```

after the exec() command. Maybe putty outputs something to the console and when the buffer is full the Shell will stop executing the program. So if the `InputStream` is not consumed properly the shell will just wait and do nothing but the process is started.

Comment: With this code, the application stay in the while loop and never exit. But no line is read.

Comment: Ah well was worth a try. It did help me when unzipping for example.